# Doctrine not updating properly entity data with several concurrent requests

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb, doctrine

I need to do something basic, I have two entities: User and Action. Each User has X tokens assigned by the Admin and then he can perform Y actions based on the amount of tokens. So lets say one User only has enough tokens to perform one Action, I identified that if I perform multiple simultaneously requests at the same exact time (like 5 or more requests at the same time). Instead of just one Action, the User executes two or more Actions (and only in the explained scenario, in the rest everything works fine)

The related code to my explanation:

```
public function useractions(Requests $request){
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $post = Request::createFromGlobals();
        if($post->request->has('new_action') && $this->isCsrfTokenValid("mycsrf", $post->request->get('csrf_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $tokens = $user->getTokens();

            if($tokens<1){
                $error = "Not enough tokens";
            }
            if(empty($error)){
                $user->setTokens($tokens-1);
                $entityManager->flush();
                $action = new Action();
                $action->setUser($user);
                $entityManager->persist($transaction);
                $entityManager->flush();
             }
         }
}
```

And I am using mariadb 10.5.12 with InnoDB as the engine

Obviously I am making a big mistake in my code or missing something in the Symfony or Doctrine configuration. Someone could tell me the mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a race condition between the user's `SELECT` (the user refresh, called by your authentication mechanism) and your `UPDATE` (the first `$entityManager->flush();`).

Doctrine has a built-in method to manage concurrent requests, the `EntityManager::transactional()` method ([doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-2-explicitly)). You may just need to wrap your code into it:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$error = $entityManager->transactional(function($entityManager) use ($user) {
    // Required to perform a blocking SELECT for UPDATE
    $entityManager->refresh($user);

    $tokens = $user->getTokens();

    if($tokens<1){
        return "Not enough tokens";
    }

    $user->setTokens($tokens-1);
    $entityManager->persist($user);
});

if (empty($error)) {
    $action = new Action();
    $action->setUser($user);
    $entityManager->persist($action);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

Note: make sure that your transaction is fast enough, as it has blocking effects on the mariadb side, affecting the involved rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems that it is exactly what I was looking for! My only question is: is transactional method blocking only the affected rows right? I mean, in this case it would add a only a lock to the affected row instead of entire users' table; right?

Comment: Yes, the transactional method uses the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` MariaDB query, which will only block the selected rows.

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks for the explanation @Alain Tiemblo Just one last thing, inside the function passed to the transactional function as I am updating the number of tokens of my user, is the transaction commited to the database without the call to flush in the entityManager? Thanks!

Comment: Also I am testing it now, but the first issue I am facing is that $user = $entityManager->refresh($user); returns a null value although $entityManager->refresh($user); works fine. And the second one is that transactional function instead of returning an empty value it returns 1, so instead of checking if error is empty should I proceed only when the errror value is equal to 1?

Comment: Sure, I wrote these lines without testing, my mistake :) my answer was here to give you the general idea, you may want to double-check the documentation anyway.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks! After testing it everything works and I just have the last question. Probably in this case it is not necessary but if I also create the new action inside the transactional function, does doctrine applies a lock to the action's entity table?

Comment: yes, all your new entities will be created inside the transaction; but take care to refresh already-managed entities (otherwise they are not selected for update/not locked)

Comment: Perfect thanks! You really taught me several things that I did not know, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

For the execution of one update command, you should use flush once, and not in each iterate.

also, you can use transactions to do all of them as one unit.

but if you want to prevent concurrency updating you should use versioning! by this, when doctrine wants to update something check versioning and if it changes throw an error and prevent to persist data to the database ( you can handle this error by a listener ) and by this way just first request will be a success.

for example, I flag updatedAt filed as a version filed and it will be checked in each persistence.

```
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 
 /**
 * @ORM\Version
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",options={"default": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
 */
private $UpdatedAt;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had been checking doctrine's docs and they say that I need to include in the form or in the user's session the current version of the entity (through a datetime or integer value). But am I not facing the same issue if several post requests are using the same version and submitted at the same exact time? (Just asking)

Comment: You don't manage the versioning, doctrine manages it. when the first request arrived and doctrine get the use, that user has a field (such as updatedAt) and it has the same value such as X,  and your process start, in the middle of this process another request arrived (second request) and both of them are in process. when the first process is finished, doctrine checks the version filed in DB and the object, if it changes it throws an error. for the first request everything is ok (X=X) and saved in DB (now version field is Y) but for the second, it has changed (X!=Y) and throw an error.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I am going to try your solution because it is valid too but unfortunately I cannot mark more than one answer as valid, I already tested the other reply but yours it is valid too and I am going to implement it too to learn more. Thanks! :)